# MySQL Case Statement based off of a count of records

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make a MySQL statement that uses a CASE statement that takes a COUNT of records and then displays a column with information based on that. I am using the Sakila Database. This is what I have so far

```
SELECT *,
CASE(
SELECT count(*) FROM  sakila.film_actor fa
WHERE fa.actor_id = a.actor_id)
WHEN 20 THEN 'Newcomer'
WHEN 30 THEN 'Prolific Actor'
ELSE 'Hollywood Star'
END actor_level

FROM sakila.film_actor fa
JOIN actor a ON fa.actor_id = a.actor_id
```

This works but I need it to be on a scale so
0-20 is Newcomer
21-30 is Prolific Actor
30+ is Hollywood Star

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `mysql`,then we can use [**IF()**](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/func_mysql_if.asp) function to do it

```
SELECT 
   IF(a.cnt <= 20,'Newcomer',a.cnt > 20 and a.cnt <= 30,'Prolific Actor','Hollywood Star')
     AS actor_level
  FROM
  (
    SELECT count(*) as cnt 
     FROM  sakila.film_actor fa
    WHERE fa.actor_id = a.actor_id
  ) a
```

Comment: there must 1 if more -   IF(a.cnt <= 20,'Newcomer',IF( a.cnt > 20 and a.cnt <= 30,'Prolific Actor','Hollywood Star'))
     AS actor_level